# Nested interval theorem for semi-open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

I came across the following cases when exploring the nested interval theorem for semi-open intervals:

**Case I**: Consider the sequence of intervals $\{[0,\frac 1n)\}$. Here, $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n = \{0\}$, which is a singleton set.

**Case II**: Consider the sequence of intervals $\{(0,\frac 1n]\}$. Here, $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n = \emptyset$, because if $I_n$ has an element $x$ in it, then $0 < x \le \frac{1}{n}$, which violates Archimedean property.

This leads me to believe that **the sequence of semi-open intervals $\{[a, b_n)\}$ where the closed bound is constant, follow the nested interval theorem**.

I have yet to come up with a general proof, but this feels intuitively right to me.

**Am I right in making the above assertion?**

Comment: What does “follow the nested interval theorem” mean? Besides, it is clear that $a\in\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[a,b_n)$.

Comment: If by "follow the nested interval theorem" you mean the infinite union is a Singleton, then it's trivially true as José said.

Comment: Yes, I did get it, I feel silly now :P. Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos!